# set() inside list comprehension inefficient?

Tags: python, list, performance, list-comprehension

I'd like to compute the difference between two lists while maintaining ordering. ("stable" removal):

Compute a list that has all values from list contained in `b` removed from list `a` while maintaining `a`'s order in the result .

I found comments that this solution is inefficient because of using `set` in a list comprehension:

```
def diff1(a, b): 
    return [x for x in a if x not in set(b)]
```

And that this is more efficient:

```
def diff2(a, b):
    bset = set(b)
    return [x for x in a if x not in bset]
```

I tried to verify it empirically. On the face of it it seems like it is true. I tried to test it using `iPython`:

```
mysetup='''
a = [1,
 2,
 3,
 4,
 5,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 6,
 7,
 8,
 9,
 10,
 11,
 12,
 13,
 14,
 15,
 16,
 17,
 18,
 19]
 
b=[3,8,9,10]
'''

s1='def diff1(a, b): return [x for x in a if x not in set(b)]'

s2='''
def diff2(a, b):
    bset = set(b)
    return [x for x in a if x not in bset]
'''
```

Result:

```
In [80]: timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=s1, number=100000000)
Out[80]: 3.826001249952242

In [81]: timeit.timeit(setup=mysetup, stmt=s2, number=100000000)
Out[81]: 3.703278487082571
```

I've tested this several times and `diff2` is consistently faster than `diff1`.

Why? Shouldn't `set(b)` inside list comprehension be computed once?

Comment: How would Python know that `set` didn't modify `b`?

Comment: There is a HUGE issue: you are not benchmarking what you think. You are benchmarking the evaluation of the function codes. The 2 functions are **never executed** in the benchmark! Thus, the results are irrelevant. Besides, the default Python implementation, CPython, performs almost no optimization. It is an interpreter, not a compiler. PyPy is smart enough to see that your benchmark does nothing and optimize it out to a no-op for example on my machine.

Comment: Even `if x not in b` is much faster, I suggest you include that.

Comment: @JérômeRichard why those two functions are not executed? Pls explain your line of reasoning.

Comment: You give an expression to `timeit` using `stmt=s1`. `s1` contain a function definition but no function call to the function defined. `timeit` just evaluate this expression but there is nothing to do besides defining the function. In fact, `timeit` have no information about the name of this function. You can put printing calls in the function to see that (at least I see that on my machine). You need to add a function call statement. I am not very familiar with `timeit` but I think you should define the functions in the setup part and then just call them in the `stmt` part.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Nah, better just get rid of the functions, i.e., reduce the strings to just the list comps (and the `bset` creation).

Comment: @KellyBundy Since some CPython optimizations (like global access and string concatenation) are only enabled on in-functions codes, isn't this better to put the code in functions? That being said, IDK if timeit already put the evaluated code in internal temporary functions.

Comment: @JérômeRichard `timeit` already puts the code into a function, see its [template](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ca8b55c7f54b38e264056148075a8061a7082013/Lib/timeit.py#L69C1-L69C1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff2` will always be faster than `diff1`, unless `a == []` because `set(b)` needs to be evaluated on every iteration of the list comprehension.

technically the list comprehension could be modifying `b` on every iteration so the inclusion check needs to be carried out on every iteration, which involves linear overhead for creating the `set` first

For instance you could write:

```
a=set([5])
[a:=set(set(a)) for _ in range(50) if set(a)]
```

Therefore the list comprehension needs to re-evaluate its condition every time.

Profiling this on a larger sample, confirms this observation:

```
import random

def generate_lists(N):
    """ Generate some random lists with some overlap and some unique elements """
    common_elements = random.sample(range(N), N//2)  
    a = random.sample(range(N*2), N)  
    b = random.sample(common_elements + random.sample(range(N*2), N//2), N)  
    return a, b

def reevaluate(a, b): 
    return [x for x in a if x not in set(b)]

def precompute(a, b):
    bset = set(b)
    return [x for x in a if x not in bset]

def no_set_usage(a,b):
    return [x for x in a if x not in b]

data_size = [1000,2000,3000,4000,5000]

approaches = [
    reevaluate,
    precompute,
    no_set_usage
]
run_performance_comparison(approaches, data_size, setup=generate_lists)
```

[image]
[image]

We can clearly see that `no_set_usage` is in the superlinear regime, probably in `O(n**2)`. We can verify this with a `sqrt` plot. To see the `O(N)` scaling of `precompute`, we need to turn to a log/log plot:

[image]
[image]

Profiling code:

```
import timeit
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import List, Dict, Callable, ContextManager

from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def data_provider(data_size, setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None):
    data = setup(data_size)
    yield data
    teardown()


def run_performance_comparison(approaches: List[Callable], data_size: List[int],
                               setup=lambda N: N, teardown=lambda: None, number_of_repetitions=5, title='N'):
    approach_times: Dict[Callable, List[float]] = {approach: [] for approach in approaches}

    for N in data_size:
        with data_provider(N, setup, teardown) as data:
            for approach in approaches:
                approach_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: approach(*data), number=number_of_repetitions)
                approach_times[approach].append(approach_time)

    for approach in approaches:
        plt.plot(data_size, approach_times[approach], label=approach.__name__)

    plt.xlabel(title)
    plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
    plt.title('Performance Comparison')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Fantastic! If you could just please add an explanation why using just plain "in b" has just about O(1) time complexity?! After all, `N` is growing obviously? If you do that, I'll accept the answer.

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U Where do you see *"just about O(1) time complexity"*?

Comment: `def no_set_usage(a,b):
    return [x for x in a if x not in b]`, orange line is about flat regardless of `N`.

Comment: I added a new picture that shows the performance in another regime and scale. I also classified the scaling of each function. Did you mean this?

Comment: @LetMeSOThat4U `no_set_usage` is the **green** line (in the image you saw). And the orange line is just "flat" at that large scale.